# Why is there sequential non-compactness in this?

Tags: general-topology

A sequence of points in the closure of an epsilon neighborhood around the origin of the topologist's sine curve does not converge because, someone told me that 0,1 is not in the curve. However, we're just considering the subspace topology on the curve so doesn't that mean the limit points in the vertical line x=0 are negligible and the curve is locally compact after all? I am a bit confused due to that - thank you.

Comment: What is the exact definition of your favoured "topologist's sine curve"?

Comment: What sequence are you talking about? Of course a constant  sequence  in the neighborhood is convergent.

Comment: The topologist's sine curve is compact, so certainly locally compact. I  define the topologist's sine curve as $(\{0\}\times [-1,1]) \cup \{(x, \sin(\frac1x): x \in (0,1]\}$

Answer (score 1):

If you define the topologist's sine curve as on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve), so

$$ T = \{(0,0)\} \cup \{(x, \sin(\frac1x)\mid x \in (0,1]\}$$

then a closed epsilon neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ is of the form $\{(x,y) \in T: \|(x,y)\| \le \epsilon\}$ and this has infinitely many points of the form $(x_n, \frac{\varepsilon}{2})$ with $x_n \to 0$. This has no convergent subsequence in $T$.

Comment: this example is like the interval $(0,1]$ which is closed in it's subspace topology. A sequence of points in the interval approaching 0 should converge by definiton because the subspace is closed.. and, that is how I wanted to view the sequences in this definition of topologist's sine curve ( on wikipedia).

Comment: @lordsharktheunknown I prefer the wikipedia definition right now.... which is without $0 \times [-1,1]$.

Comment: @kabomurphy The sequence is $s_{n} = (2/(2n+1)π, 1)$.

Comment: @7einadh not quite. You want the sine value to be $\epsilon \over 2$ not $1$

Comment: @7einadh not in $T$, that’s the problem. The only point of convergence is $(0,\frac{\epsilon}{2}) \notin T$.

Comment: Let's just think of discs around the origin for a second, if we could please, in comparison to the interval $(0,1]$; presumably there are sequences of points in $T$, which are intersections of closed discs with the *topologist's sin curve* constituting the closure of the neighborhood *A* around the origin which is also such an intersection. Now again ~ for this example ~ sequences just disprove compactness; I am confused - a sequence in the closure can't converge to any point on $X = 1$ which is not existant in this subspaces topology so how is that to disprove local compactness?

Comment: - the sequence in $cl_{\;A}$ should be closed in the subspace topology of $T$ as much as the interval $(0,1]$ is closed in it's subspace topology.

Comment: @7einadh The argument for non-local compactness is this: suppose that $(0,0)$ has a compact neighbourhood in $T$. This implies that for some $r>0$ the relative closed ball $B:=\overline{B}((0,0),r) \cap T$ is compact. Now, if $\alpha \in (0,2\pi)$ is such that $\sin(\alpha)=\frac{r}{2}$ Then for large enough $n$, $x_n=\frac{1}{\alpha+n2\pi}$ obeys that (as $x_n \to 0$)  $(x_n, \sin(\frac{1}{x_n}) = (x_n,\frac{r}{2}) \in B$ but that sequence has no convergent subsequence in $T$ (so not in $B$ either) so $B$ could not have been compact. Contradiction so $T$ is not locally compact at $(0,0)$.

Comment: @7einadh $(0,1]$ has nothing to do with it..